# Input list of items from user

Tags: list, user-interface, input, wysiwyg

I have a website with a form where users can type a free text in a textarea. I allow them to use Markdown but most of them don't use it and they usually publish crappy content, even after seeing a preview of the end result :-(

Given that most users enumerate things (job requirements) in that textarea I'm thinking that it would be great if I could somehow "force" them to create a list of items. Also, I think it would be valuable to provide them with some visual feedback while they are typing. For example, displaying some bullet points close to each item of the list they are creating and creating a new bullet point when they hit enter.

So basically, **I would like to transform a textarea in a WYSIWYG editor that only allows users to create a list of items**.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Take your pick:

https://github.com/cheeaun/mooeditable/wiki/Alternative-Javascript-WYSIWYG-editors

These can all be configured to only allow for bullets.

Comment: Thanks. I had thought about using a WYSIWYG editor with just the "list" control but in that case I'm not sure how would I prevent users from also entering regular text. I would like to enter "list mode" as soon as the users click the textarea and somehow avoid any regular text.

Comment: I'm almost certain this can be achieved with one of these editors.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer lies here:

As soon as a user focuses the textarea field, a bullet will appear. With every Enter key, a new bullet will show.
Also, a user can delete the bullet if not required and continue with normal text.

http://jsfiddle.net/abhiagrawal87/m39xt

Sample snippet:

```
$(".todolist").focus(function() {
    if(document.getElementById('todolist').value === ''){
        document.getElementById('todolist').value +='• ';
    }
});
```